# Создание и использование динамической Анимации

Tags: java, android, анимация

Всем привет, как рисовать случайные линии на фоне? То есть, просто рисовать линии на экране(на заднем фоне) и все. Как мне правильно это реализовать, на фоне relativelayout или просто View? так что бы производительность приложения не понижать, запустит в фоне в потоке отдельном и все. впервые с этим сталкиваюсь и нужны советы и направления куда копать. или может у кого  нибудь есть толковый пример.

Comment: Уточните, что именно у вас не выходит? Установить фон в Activity? Сделать фон с кастомным рисунком? Алгоритм рисования случайных линий?

Comment: Рисовать случайные линии на фоне. То есть просто рисовать линии на экране и все. Как мне правильно это реализовать, на фоне relativelayout  или просто View? так что бы производительность приложения не понижать, запустит в фоне в потоке отдельном и все. впервые с этим сталкиваюсь  и нужны советы и направления куда копать

Comment: Так отредактируйте вопрос, чтобы он действительно соответствовал тому, что вы хотите узнать.

Comment: А у вас есть какое нибудь разумное решение данного вопроса? =)

Comment: Я знаю, как рисовать линии. Но если я отвечу в этом вопросе, мой ответ будет бесполезен для всех, кроме вас. А этот форум создан не столько, чтобы решить лично вашу проблему, сколько для того, чтобы найти уже готовые ответы. А если я отвечу вам, то это будет ответ не на заданный вопрос, и его никто не сможет впоследствии найти.

Comment: Что вы предлагаете тогда??  тему я переименовал и исправил тело.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для (лейаута) или (view элемента) установите прозрачный фон `background="@android:color/transparent"`
линии рисуйте на `canvas`